# How to optimally find if "dataframe cell value" contains "cell value from another dataframe" and fill cell with it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 2 unequal columns:

| One-word | Many-Words |
| --- | --- |
| Bird | Bird with no blood |
| Stone | Stone that killed the bird |
| Blood | Bird without brains |
| <none> | stone and blood |

And i am trying to fill the new third column with all of the many-words that contain one-word. (5 or less)
So it would be like:

| One-word | Many-Words | Many-Words with One-word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bird | Bird with no blood | Bird with no blood, Stone that killed the bird, Bird without brains |
| Stone | Stone that killed the bird | Stone that killed the bird, stone and blood |
| Blood | Bird without brains | Bird without brains, Bird with no blood, stone and blood |
| <none> | stone and blood |  |

I actually found a way, but it is very slow.

1. Go with loop in column 'many-rows".

   1.1 Within loop create a dictionary, where key is cell from "many-words" and value is list made with split
2. Go with loop in column "one-word"

   2.1 Within loop create another loop in keys,values of dictionary in 1.1

   2.2.Within these to loops check whether list from 1.1 contains word from one-word

   2.3 If it does - concatenate corresponding cell in third column with the key of dictionary on a condition, that amount of concatenations is 5 or less.

I am actually looping through dataframe-column cells, and creating dicts and lists from it, which i read is very very bad.

I am novice in Python but i am pretty sure that my way is unholy.

There is got to be a better, faster, and cleaner way. Maybe something with vectorization?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterrows` to loop over your df rows and build a list of `Many-Words` containing `One-word`:

```
df["Many-Words with One-word"] = pd.Series([
  df[df["Many-Words"].str.lower().str.contains(row["One-word"].lower())]["Many-Words"].to_list()
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
])
```

Note: using `lower` to make the match case-insensitive.

Output:

```
  One-word                  Many-Words                           Many-Words with One-word
0     Bird          Bird with no blood  [Bird with no blood, Stone that killed the bir...
1    Stone  Stone that killed the bird      [Stone that killed the bird, stone and blood]
2    Blood         Bird without brains              [Bird with no blood, stone and blood]
3   <none>             stone and blood                                                 []
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
But in my case i get a column filled with NaNs
I'll try to understand your code, and maybe then i'll find some mistake on my end.

Comment: Strange. If a there was a typo in a column name, you would get a key error. Try updating pandas. For better debugging try running only the `for _, row in df.iterrows()` loop and check values of `row["One-word"]` and `df[df["Many-Words"].str.lower().str.contains(row["One-word"].lower())]`